# Auto Start Application on Reboot

Tags: javascript, .net, web-services

I would like to run an web application on a Windows 7 which is used as a kiosk (with a tactile screen). I would like to lauch a Chrome instance directly in full screen for our needs and not show the "F11" alert box with a option in the command line.And restrick all other web pages so only my web page can be searched . Is is possible ?

And any tutorial will be welcomed

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Tutorial : http://www.techiecorner.com/1941/how-to-auto-start-chrome-in-full-screen-mode-f11-everytime/ this work for me!

Comment: http://shop.inteset.com/kiosk_software_to_lockdown_windows_xp_win_7_win_8_internet_explorer_chrome

Comment: http://porteus-kiosk.org/